# equation crossed the margin (A very very long equation)

Tags: equations, align, margins

Here is my equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation} \label{eq:Vo}
        V_o = \frac{ L_3 R_3 R_L + L_3 R_2 R_L s + R_2 R_3 R_L}{X}
    \end{equation}
        where
        \begin{align*}
        X&=\bigl( C_2 C_1 L_2 L_3 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_2 L_3 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_3 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_3 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_2 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_2 R_1 R_2 R_L\bigr) s^4 \\
        &\quad+ \bigl(C_2 C_1 L_2 R_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 R_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + C_1 L_2 L_3 R_1 R_3 + C_1 L_2 L_3 R_1 R_2 + C_1 L_1 L_3 R_1 R_3 + C_1 L_1 L_3 R_1 R_2 + C_1 L_1 L_2 R_1 R_3 + C_1 L_1 L_2 R_1 R_2 + C_2 L_2 L_3 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_2 L_3 R_2 R_L + C_2 L_1 L_3 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_1 L_3 R_2 R_L + C_2 L_1 L_2 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_1 L_2 R_2 R_L\bigr) s^3 \\
        &\quad+ \bigl(C_1 L_3 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_1 L_3 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_1 L_2 R_1 R_2 R_3 + C_1 L_1 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_1 L_1 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_1 L_1 R_1 R_2 R_3 + C_2 L_3 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_3 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_2 L_2 R_2 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_2 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_2 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_2 L_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + L_2 L_3 R_3 + L_2 L_3 R_2 + L_1 L_3 R_3 + L_1 L_3 R_2 + L_1 L_2 R_3 + L_1 L_2 R_2\bigr) s^2 \\
        &\quad+ \bigl(C_1 R_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + C_2 R_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + L_3 R_3 R_L + L_3 R_2 R_L + L_3 R_1 R_3 + L_3 R_1 R_2 + L_2 R_2 R_3 + L_2 R_1 R_3 + L_2 R_1 R_2 + L_1 R_3 R_L + L_1 R_2 R_L + L_1 R_2 R_3\bigr) s + \bigl(R_2 R_3 R_L + R_1 R_3 R_L + R_1 R_2 R_L + R_1 R_2 R_3\bigr)
        \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I tried few methods that were the answers to some other questions on this same forum, but not worked, the equation runs out of margin.

Why cant there be a method which allows the ex: /quad to continue on to the next line when the margin end is encountered ?

Does someone know a trick which does stop at margin and continue where it had left from a new line until it ends and a new /quad begins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please fix the example so it is a complete (small) document so people can reproduce the problem and test answers (in particular you would need very different answers for two column or one column, most likely)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this, but is it not possible to change the notation? No one is going to read this. With this layout if one of the `R_2` should be a `C_1` it would be very hard to ever spot the error...

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:serial_Vo}
V_o = \frac{ L_3 R_3 R_L + L_3 R_2 R_L s + R_2 R_3 R_L}{X}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{flushleft}
\hangindent=3em
$
X=\bigl( C_2 C_1 L_2 L_3 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_2 L_3 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_3 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_3 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_2 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_2 R_1 R_2 R_L\bigr) s^4 
+ \bigl(C_2 C_1 L_2 R_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + C_2 C_1 L_1 R_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + C_1 L_2 L_3 R_1 R_3 + C_1 L_2 L_3 R_1 R_2 + C_1 L_1 L_3 R_1 R_3 + C_1 L_1 L_3 R_1 R_2 + C_1 L_1 L_2 R_1 R_3 + C_1 L_1 L_2 R_1 R_2 + C_2 L_2 L_3 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_2 L_3 R_2 R_L + C_2 L_1 L_3 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_1 L_3 R_2 R_L + C_2 L_1 L_2 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_1 L_2 R_2 R_L\bigr) s^3 
+ \bigl(C_1 L_3 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_1 L_3 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_1 L_2 R_1 R_2 R_3 + C_1 L_1 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_1 L_1 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_1 L_1 R_1 R_2 R_3 + C_2 L_3 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_3 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_2 L_2 R_2 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_2 R_1 R_3 R_L + C_2 L_2 R_1 R_2 R_L + C_2 L_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + L_2 L_3 R_3 + L_2 L_3 R_2 + L_1 L_3 R_3 + L_1 L_3 R_2 + L_1 L_2 R_3 + L_1 L_2 R_2\bigr) s^2 
+ \bigl(C_1 R_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + C_2 R_1 R_2 R_3 R_L + L_3 R_3 R_L + L_3 R_2 R_L + L_3 R_1 R_3 + L_3 R_1 R_2 + L_2 R_2 R_3 + L_2 R_1 R_3 + L_2 R_1 R_2 + L_1 R_3 R_L + L_1 R_2 R_L + L_1 R_2 R_3\bigr) s + 
\bigl(R_2 R_3 R_L + R_1 R_3 R_L + R_1 R_2 R_L + R_1 R_2 R_3\bigr)
$
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know that spotting something in this equation is hard. But C represents capacitor value and R represent resistor value and they have to be kept as they are. It just represents the system, I dont know what the reader gets other than the complexity of the system, but further explanation is what clears the mysterious air around these kind of long equations. But still I have to represent the system in terms of equation so I am just obliged to put this. I hope I explained what you asked. Thanks a lot.